why is the useState hook being invoked twice?
git: https://github.com/techybolek/DUP-TESTCASE
This example is intended to be a testcase demonstrating a duplicate hook for the following scenario:

The user types in a query and presses the Send button
A new Conversation object is initialized and added to the list existing conversations
An invokeServerAPI function is called with the query as the parameter and the callback function to be invoked for each response steps. There may be multiple response steps for each query and I want to display them immediately as they come in from the server
The response is added to the current conversation. However the setConversations hook is invoked twice for each step, even though updateCurrentConversation is called only once.

Console output:
page.tsx:25 Text response received: Response for query:sample query 1
page.tsx:31 Invoke updateCurrentConversation with response:  Response for query:sample query 1
page.tsx:31 Invoke updateCurrentConversation with response:  Response for query:sample query 1

Source:
"use client"

import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

export default function MyApp() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);
  const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const startTime = new Date()
    const newConversation = { query: input, startTime, responses: [] }
    setConversations((prevConversations) => [...prevConversations, newConversation]);

    try {
      await invokeServerAPI(input, textHandler)
    }
    finally {
      setInput('');
    }

    function textHandler(text) {
      console.log("Text response received:", text)
      updateCurrentConversation(text)
    }

    function updateCurrentConversation(data) {
      setConversations((prevConversations) => {
        console.log('Invoke updateCurrentConversation with response: ', data)
        const index = prevConversations.findIndex(conversation => conversation.startTime === startTime);
        const _newConversation = { ...prevConversations[index] };
        _newConversation.responses.push({ data })
        return [
          ...prevConversations.slice(0, index),
          _newConversation,
          ...prevConversations.slice(index + 1)
        ];
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col h-screen">
      <div className="overflow-y-scroll flex-grow p-2">
        {conversations.map((conversation, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="mb-5">
            <p>{conversation.startTime.toLocaleString()} <span className="font-bold">{conversation.query})</span>:</p>
            {conversation.responses
              .map((response, respIndex) => {
                return (
                  <div key={index * 1000 + respIndex} className="mb-2">
                      <pre className="mt-2 bg-gray-100 p-2 rounded border border-gray-300 whitespace-pre-wrap">{response.data}</pre>
                  </div>
                );
              })
            }
          </div>
        ))}
        <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
      </div>
      <div className="p-2 bg-gray-800 text-white">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="flex justify-start space-x-4">
            <div className="flex flex-col" style={{ marginRight: '1rem', marginLeft: '0' }}>
              <label className="text-black" style={{ color: 'black', display: 'block', width: 'auto' }}>Query:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={input}
                onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
                className="p-2 bg-gray-300 text-black rounded-md"
                style={{ fontSize: '18px', color: 'black', height: '40px', width: '500px' }}
                placeholder="Enter your query here"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col items-start">
              <label style={{ color: 'black', display: 'block', width: 'auto' }}>&nbsp;</label>
              <button type="submit" className="bg-green-500 text-white rounded-md hover:bg-green-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-50"
                style={{ paddingLeft: '1rem', paddingRight: '1rem', height: '40px', marginLeft: '0' }}>Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div >
  );
}

export function invokeServerAPI(theQuery, theHandler) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    //simulate just one response
    theHandler('Response for query:' + theQuery)
    resolve(null);
  })
}


Any chance you're using react's StrictMode?

When you call setState, it triggers a re-render if the value has been changed.

@zerkms I'm not using strict mode.

Oh well. it turned out the strict mode was implicitly turned on, because it's a nextjs app. Set it to off, and now setState is called only once.

Why would you turn off development tools that help you write correct code? Leave it enabled and try to understand it's enabled by default for a reason (i.e. to help you write better code) and is only enabled in non-production builds.

@DrewReese You are probably right. However I'm at a loss what else to do.

What do you mean, other than disabling StrictMode, which I don't recommend, the only other option is to leave it enabled and reap the benefits. As I said, leaving it enabled helps you write better code. It's a no-brainier in my opinion. When your smoke alarm goes off you don't fix it by removing the battery to turn the alarm off, you go find the source of the smoke and put it out.

@DrewReese If I let it invoke twice it breaks my application, because the responses are added twice. I've tried filtering out, counting the calls and what not but I couldn't get it to work. I may be missing something. I humbly admit I don't understand the rationale behind setState being invoked twice and I don't know how to handle it. By handling  I mean in my particular case, how to prevent things from being added twice. If there is any guidance how to handle setState being invoked twice I'd appreciate.

The setState invokes twice in strict mode in React. In Next JS to turn off strict mode edit your next.config.mjs as shown below and your strict mode will be turned off.
You can also check out the reactStrictMode documentation.
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: false,
};

export default nextConfig;


import React from 'react';

function ExampleApplication() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <React.StrictMode>
        <div>
          <ComponentOne />
          <ComponentTwo />
        </div>
      </React.StrictMode>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

If there is a React.StrictMode in the index.js file remove that.

I'm not using strict mode.

your stackblitz playgroud is not working, can you please fix that

Sorry, had to remove it from the post.
